# Electron / Angular project Onload show image as splash

Tags: angular, electron

I have an Angular / Electron application.

What the application loads I need to show an image as a splash screen which then disappears when it finishes loading.

In my index.html I have:

```
<app-root>Loading ...</app-root>
```

But I never see it ... I need an image where the Loading... is and for it to stay for a few seconds and then disappear.

For example:

```
<app-root><div id="splash"><img src="assets/splash.png" /></div></app-root>
```

I have been searching on google but cannot find anything, that's why I don't have any code to show.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about angular, but I have an electron application with a splashscreen

you need to create a separate window for the splashscreen, show it first then close it when your application is ready

the structure looks like this :

#### splash.js

```js
const path = require('path')

const StandardWindow = require('./StandardWindow')
const loadCss = require('./loadCss')

function splash () {
  const splashScreen = new StandardWindow({
    file: 'splash.html',
    width: 450,
    height: 200,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }) // building the splashscreen window

  splashScreen.show() // showing it immediately

  splashScreen.onDidFinishLoad = function () {
    loadCss(this, path.join(__dirname, 'splash.css'))
  } // loading the splash css after html loading

  return splashScreen
}

module.exports = splash
```

#### loadCss.js

```js
const fs = require('fs')

function loadCss (elWindow, cssPath) {
  fs.readFile(
    cssPath,
    'utf-8',
    (error, data) => {
      if (error) throw error
      const css = data.replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ').trim()
      elWindow.webContents.insertCSS(css)
      console.log('loaded css :' + css.substring(0, 20) + '...')
    }
  )
}

module.exports = loadCss
```

#### StandardWindow.js

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

const loadCss = require('./loadCss')

// default window settings
const defaultProps = {
  width: 500,
  height: 800,
  show: false,

  // update for electron V5+
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
}

class StandardWindow extends BrowserWindow {
  constructor ({
    file,
    devTools,
    onDidFinishLoad,
    onReadyToShow,
    ...windowSettings
  }) {
    console.log('creating StandardWindow ...')
    // calls new BrowserWindow with these props
    super({ ...defaultProps, ...windowSettings })

    this.loadFile(file)

    if (devTools) this.webContents.openDevTools()

    this.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
      loadCss(this, path.join(__dirname, '/shared.css'))
      if (onDidFinishLoad) onDidFinishLoad()
      if (this.onDidFinishLoad) this.onDidFinishLoad()
    })

    // gracefully show when ready to prevent flickering
    this.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      this.show()
      if (onReadyToShow) onReadyToShow()
      if (this.onReadyToShow) this.onReadyToShow()
    })

    console.log('...StandardWindow created')
  }
}

module.exports = StandardWindow
```

#### then in your main.js

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

const splash = require('./splash/splash')
const StandardWindow = require('./StandardWindow')


app.on('ready', function () {
  let splashscreen = splash()

  //then just create your main window and start your processes
  let mainWindow = new StandardWindow({
    devTools: true,
    file: 'main.html',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      // preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    },
    onDidFinishLoad: _ => {
      splashScreen.close()
      splashScreen = null
      // close your splashscreen when window ready !
    }
  })
})


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

then you just have to create 'splash.html' and 'splash.js' to code your splashscreen and 'main.html' for your main window ...

Hope that helps a little